# Creating images for android

Tags: android, image, sdk

I'm currently creating an app for android that's going to need multiple images. Backgrounds, an image for the icon, and images for the buttons that I'll have. What's the best way to create an image for an android application and how would you implement them into the app so that they work? Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a non-artist developer, creating production-quality images can be hard and probably best jobbed out to a graphics person. Partnering with a graphics/sound person can be a good solution.

For early development or other stuff that doesn't need to be production quality, I start with GIMP. Then for icons and buttons that need to be scalable, I use the free site [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html) to create 9-patch images.

Comment: Thank. Took your advice and found someone who specializes in graphical design. Gimp is complicated and I don't have time to learn it.